# Document, Music, Videos, Desktop and other files of that kind in my languange that I set as default during installation

Tags: 16.04, home-directory, language-support

So, I just installed 16.04, and during the proccess I selected Croatian as my language for the installation. I selected it so it would be easier to read everything for me, as it is the default language of mine.
Now, when everything is installed, I switched my system language to English, and the folders in my home/[username]/ are in Croatian. (Documents, Videos, Music, Pictures, Desktop). They are all in Croatian.
I tried to siply rename them, but after I restarted the laptop, it said that the Preuzimanja folder(Downloads in my language) is missing, and that I have to set it up with some sort of blueman app.

Can anyone help me? this is really annoying me.

Comment: Run this: `xdg-user-dirs-update --force`

Comment: But my home Desktop directory is still under the same name as before...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a duplicate, so you simply can remove the other? (Possibly after having moved the files in it to the new one.)

Comment: okay works now. it was a duplicate and I also had to restart to see it work. Thanks for the help!